# Redshift - copying multiple manifest files

Tags: amazon-web-services, copy, amazon-redshift

I'm using AWS Redshift to load multiple S3 files via a COPY command. I'm doing this via a manifest. We may have multiple manifest files that will need to be loaded into Redshift at any point in time. What is the best way of loading multiple manifest files into Redshift?

Is it possible to execute the copy command passing a list/array of manifest files like below?

```
copy schema.table_name
from 's3://my-bucket/manifest1.manifest', 's3://my-bucket/manifest2.manifest', 's3://my-bucket/manifest3.manifest'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=XXXX;aws_secret_access_key=YYYY'
manifest gzip format as json 'auto';
```

Or is it ok to execute multiple copy commands from different applications without having it affect the overall performance of Redshift too much? My concern with executing multiple copy commands in parallel is that it'll introduce resource contention when executing the copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I ended up doing was joining the contents of the multiple manifest files into an uber manifest. Thus instead of executing 500 separate COPY commands for 500 manifest files, I concatenated the contents of the 500 manifests into an uber manifest and then executed the Redshift COPY.

The performance improvement was significant. Redshift COPY of a single manifest took about 3 minutes. Concatenating the 500 into 1 uber manifest took between 45-90 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with running one big COPY for a lot of data is that the Redshift will allocate the maximum size of the expected table on the disk, which could lead to DISK FULL exception, that you can avoid if you would split the COPY commands into several COPYs (*That will run one after the other. **NOT** simultaneously).
It's also important to take in mind the number of cores that you have in your Redshift Cluster, in order to maximize the parallelism.

Comment: There is already a solution and even more OP solved his own issue by himself.

Comment: I know, but I thought it is important to mention that his solution might not work for all cases, and it's important for people that are getting here (like I did) to know that in advance

Comment: Ok, since you are convinced of your solution it's fine. May it stay here. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can run multiple copy commands and of course it will affect performance. You just need to do some tests to gauge the level of slowdown you can accept.

If you want to limit the number of copy that can run concurrently, you can create a new user and follow [Tutorial: Configuring Workload Management (WLM) Queues to Improve Query Processing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-configuring-workload-management.html). Say you set the concurrency to 1 then you can fire up multiple commands and only 1 of them will be running.